# nodemailer failing with namecheap private email

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, namecheap

I've searched this site for an answer that worked and have found nothing.

I'm trying to setup nodemailer and keep receiving this error:

```
{"code":"EENVELOPE","command":"API"}
```

Here's the setup code. I've tried with and without `TLS` (`port: 465` and `port: 587` with both combinations of `secure: true` and `secure: false`)

nodejs code:

```
function(resetToken, user, done) {
            let smtpConfig = nodemailer.createTransport({
                host: 'mail.privateemail.com',
                port: 587,
                secure: false,
                auth: {
                    user: 'email',
                    pass: 'pass'
                }
            });
            let mailOptions = {
                to: user.email,
                from: 'email',
                subject: 'Password Reset For app',
                text: 'Reset this'
            };
            smtpConfig.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info) {
                if(err) {
                    res.json({
                        'message': err,
                        'info': info
                    });
                }
                res.json({
                    'message': 'Click the link in the email we just sent to reset your password'
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: your from should be a registered and valid email `let mailOptions = {
                to: user.email,
                from:<your registed emailId>,
                subject: 'Password Reset For app',
                text: 'Reset this'
            }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it works just fine for me. This is my setup

```
var transporter = `nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'mail.privateemail.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
      user: 'user',
      pass: 'pass'
  }
});
var mailOptions = {
              from: 'contact@domain.com',
              to: req.body.email,
              subject: 'Hi there',
              text: 'I work'
            };
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
              if (error) {
                console.log(error);
              } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
              }
            });`
```

And it works on secure port too.(465)

Comment: Must be my namecheap private email setup. I'll test this with another email I have and see if it works.

Comment: I am no expert, but in my code the transporter is defined outside the function that sends the mail. Perhaps is that? Im still learning myself :)